# perl regex: cant understand what /^#/ is supposed to be matching

Tags: regex, perl, caret

Got a script which Im trying to debug but I cant figure out the meaning of this regex and googling "caret" and "pound" isnt helping.

```
$line !~ /^#/
```

Not a complicated question I'm sure but I'm locked away from all my perl books until after xmas!

I know that the `!~` means 'doesnt match...' of course!

Comment: You're on the internet. http://perldoc.perl.org/ and especially http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: There's no answers I can find on the internet on what # does in a regex as Ive just found out that it's just a plain text character. That's why I had to ask real people.

Comment: It can be a special character if `/x` is in effect, but then it is a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caret is beginning of line. # is a #. It's looking for non-comment lines (and assuming comments start in the first column, or at least at the beginning of whatever `line` is).

Comment: Thanks. I thought # was a special character (I should have pointed out that I already know what ^ means though)

Answer (score 1):

This is checking for all lines that do not start with "#".   Typically comments in many programming language.

Comment: true, ^ means occurring at the beginning of the line, the # is just that, a #.